# Is it alright for two people to simultaneously be logged into a WP site as administrator?

Tags: login

I have given the admin log-in details of my site to a friend who is helping me sort out a problem. If I log in at the same time she is logged in, will it cause a problem? Or can we both be logged in at the same time?

Comment: Technically this shouldn't be a problem, but I would recommend setting up a separate admin account for your friend just the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a newer version of WordPress, you'll see that you can't both edit the same page/post because it will show that as locked (you can take over though). I agree that a separate admin account would be good. WordPress is designed to support many users logged in and active. The only issue becomes if you are doing administration such as settings/tools/widget/theme modifications where actions can be overridden by the other person. I would suggest an open line of communication as you work. In a development environment, the same applies if you have multiple hands on the same project and can't resolve in a local environment with SVN/Git control.

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine - just the same as if you log in using two tabs.

Be aware that if the other user does something, you will need to refresh to see it, but that's no different from if they have their own login.

Comment: Is there any official resource that proves what you are saying?

Comment: An editor is complaining that some changes have been reverted and I now for fact that they are editing the website with the same user from different machines. Example: editor A opens a post, editor B opens same post, editor B make some edits and save, editor A make some edits and save: result the post shows only edits made by editor A. Can it happen? From your answer I assume it can't.

Comment: That is exactly what I would expect. It's not going to be sophisticated enough to merge different users edits together, it will keep the last one. By "it will be fine" I meant that it won't log the other user out or cause anything to actually break if you are both looking around.

Comment: That's clearer, thanks.

Comment: Also note this answer is almost 6 years old. I haven't used Wordpress recently.

Comment: If use A has post 123 open for editing, user B will get a warning if they try to edit it. They have the option to not edit, or take over editing from A. 

The only way to lose info is if A makes some changes and does NOT save them, and B takes over, A's edits are lost.

Answer (score 0):

My two admins, we save the new edits as page Drafts while every admin is working.  After every admin is complete, either one admin publishes all the draft pages or ends their posting session and allows the other admins to publish their work one at a time. That way we don't override one another.